# How to implement a logging Interceptor for Python async gRPC client?

Tags: python, asynchronous, logging, grpc, interceptor

I'm trying to implement accept / error logging for an asynchronous gRPC clientwith [gRPC AsyncIO API](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_asyncio.html#). I would like to handle common errors (like `StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE`) in one place instead of in every request.

It's easy for the synchronous version with `response.exception()`:

```python
class LoggingClientInterceptor(grpc.UnaryUnaryClientInterceptor):
    def __init__(self, logger: Logger):
        self.logger = logger

    def intercept_unary_unary(self, continuation, client_call_details, request):
        self.logger.debug(f"{request=}")
        response = continuation(client_call_details, request)
        if response.exception():
            self.logger.exception(f"{response.code()}")
        return response
```

But things get more complicated when using an asynchronous interceptor.

I tried to use try / except, expecting `await` returns a response, but this did not lead to anything, because await of `continuation` returns an undone `UnaryUnaryCall` and it has no method `.exception`:

```python
# this does not work
class LoggingClientInterceptor(grpc.aio.UnaryUnaryClientInterceptor):
    def __init__(self, logger: Logger):
        self.logger = logger

    async def intercept_unary_unary(self, continuation, client_call_details, request):
        self.logger.debug(f"{request=}")
        try:
            response = await continuation(client_call_details, request)
            return response
        except Exception as exc:
            self.logger.exception(f"{exc}")
```

I can await the response code and compare it with OK, and then throw an exception, but it seems to me that this is somehow the wrong way: what if I want to add another interceptor?

```
code = await response.code()
if code != grpc.StatusCode.OK:
    raise SmthException
```

I have searched extensively, including the code in the [official repository](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/python/interceptors), but have not found good examples for asynchronous interceptors

I will be glad if someone will show me the reference sample.

Answer (score 0):

Having similar problem and adjust the code a little bit.

```
class LoggingClientInterceptor(grpc.aio.UnaryUnaryClientInterceptor):
    def __init__(self, logger: Logger):
        self.logger = logger

    async def intercept_unary_unary(self, continuation, client_call_details, request):
        self.logger.debug(f"{request=}")
        try:
            undone_call = await continuation(client_call_details, request)
            response = await undone_call
            return response
        except Exception as exc:
            self.logger.exception(f"{exc}")
            raise exc
```